# Downcast with static cast

Tags: c++, c++20

I have this hierarchy (methods are simplified):

```cpp
struct BaseExpr {
  explicit BaseExpr(ExprType expr_type) : expr_type_(expr_type) {}

  virtual ~BaseExpr() = default;

  template<typename T>
  T const* As() const {
    if (expr_type_ == T::expr_type) {
      return static_cast<T const*>(this);
    }

    return nullptr;
  }

  ExprType expr_type_;
};

//CRTP
template<typename T>
struct Expr : public BaseExpr {
  Expr() : BaseExpr(T::expr_type) {}

  ~Expr() override = default;
};

struct Variable : public Expr<Variable> {
  static ExprType const expr_type = ExprType::kVariable;

  // ...other methods

  std::string name_;
};
```

Sometimes i need to downcast a pointer of a `BaseExpr`, to a concrete class, e.g. `Variable`, but i don't want to use `dynamic_cast`. So i store another static member (`expr_type`) for comparison purpose. Is this approach good? Or perhaps there a better of doing such thing?

Comment: As long as you aren't using multiple inheritance this usually works fine.

Comment: Sooo... You are basically doing what `dynamic_cast` is doing, except at a higher level, with added code complexity. How is this better than `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: "*Sometimes i need to downcast a pointer of a BaseExpr, to a concrete class, e.g. Variable, but i don't want to use dynamic_cast*" If you have written yourself into a situation where this is a thing you want, you need to stop and re-examine how you got here and what it is you're really trying to do. You should not be writing code where this kind of thing is common enough to need a dedicated function rather than just `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain _why_ you "don't want to use" `dynamic_cast`.  It would likely improve the quality of your answers, since your goals would be better understood.

Comment: `Is this approach good?` No! dynamic_cast or casting based on some runtime value is usually indication of incorrect design of abstractions. Whole point of OOP is to be able operate on base type without knowing what are the details of the actual object. Now since you didn't provide information what this code exactly should do it is impossible to tell how this can be achieved in better way.

Comment: @bolov It's faster. A lot faster. Most `dynamic_cast` implementations rely on string comparisons for multi or virtual inheritance, and it can still fallback to string comparisons for single inheritance. This is a simple integer comparison, and then a `static_cast`, which is mostly done at the language level. The only time `static_cast` actually does something in assembly when manipulating object pointer, is when it needs to adjust the pointer to correctly point to the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already paying for the cost of having a vtable, since you're using virtual functions and the like. So unless performance is a real problem (as evidenced by profiling), if you really, *really* need to do this (and you should definitely reconsider any code where you need to do this), just use `dynamic_cast`. It makes it clear that you're doing a thing that's at least somewhat dubious at the site where you're doing the operation.

Your method works only to the extent that:

1. You don't use multiple inheritance or `virtual` inheritance.
2. Everyone who creates a new type adds an appropriate value to `ExprType` (however that may work, whether an enum or some kind of hash).

Answer (score 2):

The 'dynamic_cast' will work in the situation like

```
class A { public : virtual void foo(); }
class B : public A { }
class C : public B { }

A *base = new C;
B *intermediate =dynamic_cast<B*>(base);
```

and you need to downcast from A to B while the real object is of type C. And your solution won't, since it recognizes only specific types, not hierarchies.

And it won't work with multiple inheritance inheritance.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` won't work here. `A` needs to have a virtual function.

Comment: [This solution will not comple](https://godbolt.org/z/3z4bbYcWd).

Comment: Folks (@Pete, @Drew), this was just dummy code to show the hierarchy, it wasn't intended to be compilable or runnable; I am sure people got the idea. Anyway, "fixed" to avoid confusion. (A strange thing, I am sure that I left a similar comment here yesterday, but it somehow disappeared; testing again).

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is likely to be more performance efficient, since it is restricted to your scenario.

However you'll have to maintain unique `ExprType` values, and also you cannot handle stuff like multi-level hierarchies, not to mention multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Using static cast, assuming when you know and are confident of the derivative type is, in my experience, a very effective way of having single inheritance RTTI, without all the string comparisons.

I personally do this so often that I've written macros that handle the cast. Here is a simplified version of it:

```
// Used in the header of the derived class.
#define RTT_IMPL(TYPE) \
    static void* _getStaticRuntimeType();          \
    virtual void* _getRuntimeType() const override \
    {                                              \
        return TYPE::_getStaticRuntimeType();      \
    }

// Used in a translation unit.
#define RTT_IMPL_TU(TYPE) \
    void* TYPE::_getStaticRuntimeType()            \
    {                                              \
        static int magicHandle = 0;                \
        return &magicHandle;                       \
    }                                              \

// Used in the header of the base class.
#define RTT_BASE_IMPL(TYPE) virtual void* _getRuntimeType() const = 0;

// Used in the header of the base class.
#define RTT_BASE_CHECK(TYPE) \
    template<typename T>                                        \
    bool _isRuntimeType() const                                 \
    {                                                           \
        return T::_getStaticRuntimeType() == _getRuntimeType(); \
    }                                                           \
    template<typename T>                                        \
    static bool _isRuntimeType(const TYPE& obj)                 \
    {                                                           \
        return obj._isRuntimeType<T>();                         \
    }

// Used in the header of the base class.
#define RTT_BASE_CAST(TYPE) \
    template<typename T>                                              \
    T* _castRuntimeType()                                             \
    {                                                                 \
        return _isRuntimeType<T>() ? static_cast<T*>(this) : nullptr; \
    }                                                                 \
    template<typename T>                                              \
    static T* _castRuntimeType(const TYPE& obj)                       \
    {                                                                 \
        return obj._castRuntimeType<T>();                             \
    }

#define RTT_CHECK(_VAR, T) (std::remove_pointer_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(_VAR)>>::_isRTType<T>(_VAR))
#define RTT_CAST(_VAR, T) (std::remove_pointer_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(_VAR)>>::_castRTType<T>(_VAR))
```

The `BASE` macros are placed within the base class, `RTT_IMPL` is placed in the derived class definition, and `RTT_IMPL_TU` is placed within a translation unit (CPP file).

The `RTT_IMPL_TU` being a separate macro is necessary for this to work across shared library boundaries. If you do use this across shared library boundaries you will need to decorate the function declaration in the header with the appropriate compiler attribute (`__declspec(dllexport)`, `__declspec(dllimport)`, `__attribute__((visibility("default")))`, etc).

The `magicHandle` can really be anything, we just need a value that will always be unique to that type. In this case because we have it as a static member of a static function its address will remain constant, and that address is what becomes our unique identifier.

This is only the baseline of what I typically use. I also have many wrapper functions that can handle taking in a wide variety of pointer types (raw pointers, shared pointers, weak pointers, etc).

## Why is this better than a `dynamic_cast`

`dynamic_cast` is implemented using RTTI. There are many good reasons for disabling RTTI, one of them is all the debug strings it leaves around making it easier to reverse an executable. There is also the factor of executable size from these strings. These strings are the key to how `dynamic_cast` is typically implemented. Most implementations that I have seen (the Windows x64 ABI, most Linux x64 ABI's, and the Macho ABI) use string comparisons to check the type of the object. This is incredibly slow, especially compared to checking an integer, and then performing a `static_cast` (which is mostly at the language level, and at most has some pointer arithmetic to adjust for the derived class).

On Windows with Visual Studio you can find the implementation of `dynamic_cast` in your installation folder: `2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/%VERSION%/ctr/src/vcruntime/rtti.cpp`. If the type only has single inheritance it use a simpler casting routine that mostly doesn't rely on string comparisons, but it can still fallback to that. Additionally that routine is designed to handle deep levels of inheritance, where every level is a potential for a cast resut. If you only have single level inheritance, or you don't need to cast to any of the intermediate levels this will be a lot faster.

One answer implies that the cost of VTable and a `dynamic_cast` is the same. This is not the case. Calling a virtual function simply requires dereferncing the first member of the object to get the vtable, then dereferencing the member of vtable, and then perform an indirect jump. This is a very fast process on modern CPU's. `dynamic_cast` doesn't actually call any virtual functions (and even if it does, thats on top of, not in place of, the other performance implications), it accesses the static RTTI data to know if the type is correct, and then uses that data to compute how much the object pointer needs to be manipulated to correctly point to the derived type.

### But, premature optimization is evil!!!

I could go on for hours about what that quote is actually talking about, but needless to say, optimization isn't bad. Ultimately there is nothing more permanent than a temporary solution, so optimize from the beginning, because it's not going to be done later.

Additionally, `dynamic_cast`s implemented with string comparisons have been consistently shown to take up measurable amounts of time. Given OP is writing what appears to be a compiler, a process which can run for very long periods of time during the optimization phase, this is almost certainly a worthwhile optimization, and ultimately doesn't take that much time to implement.

Optimization is balance of performance gained, compared to effort used. If there is a faster way of implementing a function, and it doesn't take substantially more work to implement, I will always opt for the faster method. It doesn't matter if the performance gain is in nanoseconds, by always considering the performance of something I know what to look for when I have to optimize the hotpath.

Comment: This implementation won't work across shared library boundaries.

Comment: What I mean is, if `_getStaticRuntimeType` is defined in the header, I think each shared library will get its own `static int magicHandle` instance for the same type, so the addresses won't match.

Comment: I did some tests, and the original implementation should probably work as is on Linux. I expected `__declspec(import)`/`__declspec(export)` to be necessary on Windows, but at least on MinGW it worked without them. Can't test on MSVC right now.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Due to the compiler specificity of shared symbols I've decided to add it as a comment, and not give any explicit code. Thank you for doing actual compilation tests, that extends far beyond what is necessary. I think that should cover all of the major issues, this is supposed to be quite generalized, so I think anything else can be an exercise to the reader in actual implementation.